# Combining API and web views in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

As of Rails 5, API gem is in merged in.

Now, what does that leave us with in case I have API to call via AJAX from the webpage? I'm looking for a best practice here. Surely, I can make a route with JSON serializer myself. Then, there is a possibility to entirely separate API calls into another app.

Since API functionality is called by inheritance `class ApplicationController < ActionController::API` I can't really see an option to combine the it with standard `ApplicationController < ActionController` call.

Am I right? Would overloading on per-controller basis work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use the `--api` mode I think that you are right - you could not combine those. And this is made by design - `ActionController::API` is a subclass of `ActionController::Metal`. The idea is to have `ActionController::API` very skinny and lightweight. But, by enabling the *api mode* you create a "contract" that your application will be just an API, and that is it.

**But**, you could always have a both, a normal and an API controller in the same application, if you are using a normal Rails app. Then, the `ActionController::API` class will be available as well, so you can have an `API` namespace containing only the lightweight `API` controllers, and the rest in the global namespace.

For example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  * some code here *
end
```

and:

```
class API::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController::API
  * some code here *
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @BhushanLodha I haven't benchmarked this, but I doubt that the lack of a few abstraction layers will make a substantial difference in performance. I'd be glad to be proven wrong if someone has any data proving the opposite.